# Theano.function equivalent in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, theano, tensorflow

I am wondering if there is any equivalent to

```
theano.function(inputs=[x,y], # list of input variables
outputs=..., # what values to be returned
updates=..., # “state” values to be modified
givens=...,  # substitutions to the graph)
```

in TensorFlow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `run` method on the [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) class is quite close to `theano.function`. Its `fetches` and `feed_dict` arguments are moral equivalents of `outputs` and `givens`.

Answer (score 1):

Theano's `function` returns an object that acts like a Python function and executes the computational graph when called. In TensorFlow, you execute computational graph using session's `run` method. If you want to have a similar Theano-style function object that you can call, you could use `TensorFlowTheanoFunction` wrapper below as a drop-in replacement for theano's `function`

```
class TensorFlowTheanoFunction(object):   
  def __init__(self, inputs, outputs):
    self._inputs = inputs
    self._outputs = outputs

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    feeds = {}
    for (argpos, arg) in enumerate(args):
      feeds[self._inputs[argpos]] = arg
    return tf.get_default_session().run(self._outputs, feeds)

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
c = a+b
d = a-b
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
f = TensorFlowTheanoFunction([a, b], [c, d])
print f(1, 2)
```

You will see

```
[3, -1]
```