# Theano function equivalent in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano

I'm wonder wrt this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366970/theano-function-equivalent-in-tensorflow)

I want to resolve **update** issue in **Theano.function** with this lazy **tensorflow** constrution:

```
class TensorFlowTheanoFunction(object):
def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, session):
    self._inputs = inputs
    self._outputs = outputs
    self.session = session

def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    feeds = {}
    for (argpos, arg) in enumerate(args):
        feeds[self._inputs[argpos]] = arg
    return self.session.run(self._outputs, feeds)
```

If I want to pass an **update** argument (like in Theano) how I can modify this lazy call?
I just want that this can also work in tensorflow:

```
self.new = theano.function([], [], updates=zip(old_params, params))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modifying Yaroslav's code from that thread to use tf.assign, with a control dependency to make sure the outputs are computed before the assignments happen:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class TensorFlowTheanoFunction(object):   
  def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, updates=()):
    self._inputs = inputs
    self._outputs = outputs
    self._updates = updates

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    feeds = {}
    for (argpos, arg) in enumerate(args):
      feeds[self._inputs[argpos]] = arg
    try:
      outputs_identity = [tf.identity(output) for output in self._outputs]
      output_is_list = True
    except TypeError:
      outputs_identity = [tf.identity(self._outputs)]
      output_is_list = False
    with tf.control_dependencies(outputs_identity):
      assign_ops = [tf.assign(variable, replacement) 
                    for variable, replacement in self._updates]
    outputs_list = tf.get_default_session().run(
        outputs_identity + assign_ops, feeds)[:len(outputs_identity)]
    if output_is_list:
      return outputs_list
    else:
      assert len(outputs_list) == 1
      return outputs_list[0]

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
variable = tf.get_variable(
    "variable", shape=[], dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
c = a + b + variable
d = a - b
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
f = TensorFlowTheanoFunction([a, b], [c, d], updates=[(variable, variable + 1)])
print f(1, 2)
print f(1, 2)
print f(0, 2)
f = TensorFlowTheanoFunction([a, b], c, updates=[(variable, variable + 1)])
print f(1, 2)
print f(1, 2)
print f(0, 2)
```

This updates the variable at each iteration:

```
[3, -1]
[4, -1]
[4, -2]
6
7
7
```

Comment: hm, I've got an error with my previous code wrt this new implementation of function:

**raise TypeError("'Tensor' object is not iterable.")**

some stack:

`prev_call> val = TensorFlowTheanoFunction([self.input], self.get_output(), session)`

`err_call> outputs_identity = [tf.identity(output) for output in self._outputs]`

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I've added a special case for when outputs is a scalar.

Comment: Sorry for delay. It seems to me that it works after these corrections, but a bit slower (100-200 times slower). Anyway, thx for help!

Comment: Slower than the equivalent Theano, or slower than the version without variable updates? I'd be curious about what you're benchmarking.

Comment: Slower than TF version without updates. I just run the same code with previous and new function. The second one suddenly occurs more slower

Comment: Presumably using the variable update option of the new function? If you don't care when the variable updates happen (before or after the values are computed, or somewhere between), you could remove the control dependency. Even if you do care, it might be helpful to see if that speeds things up. Could be an interesting new question (not that I necessarily have a good answer for you).